# How do I draw a full screen quad in DirectX 11?

Tags: directx11

How do I draw a full screen quad that shows red on the screen?

Comment: If you are new to DirectX 11, you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) and the [tutorials](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) for it.

Answer (score 3):

First, set the primitive topology to TRIANGLESTRIP (ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetPrimitiveTopology), set the following shaders then call devicecontext->Draw(4,0). You don't even need vertex buffers for this because of the automatic system value of vertex id in the shader.

```
float4 VertexShader(uint vI : SV_VERTEXID):SV_POSITION
{
    float2 texcoord = float2(vI&1,vI>>1); //you can use these for texture coordinates later
    return float4((texcoord.x-0.5f)*2,-(texcoord.y-0.5f)*2,0,1);
}

float4 PixelShader(float4 pos : SV_POSITION):SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(1,0,0,1); //the red color
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this solution requires shader model 4.0 and Direct3D feature level 10.0+ hardware.